# Cookie changes made in EndRequest are not sent in Response

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have logic that modifies cookies in the `EndRequest` method and this works perfectly in WebForms and MVC<sup>1</sup>.

But I've just discovered that it does not work in WebApi, even though it looks like it should.

When I call a WebApi method `MyMethod`, if the method sets a cookie, I see it in the response. But even though `EndRequest` **does fire** after `MyMethod` and **does set** the needed cookie, the updated cookie **does not** get sent in the request. It seems that you can't modify the Response cookies in `EndRequest`, but I can't figure out why, and what to do about it.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here, and what to do about it so that I can run my needed logic without having to explicitly call it in every web method? If I need to modify the Response, what is the right way to capture the intent of `EndRequest` within WebApi?

---

[1] It's not directly relevant to the question, but the reason is so that I can secure cookies against tampering by hashing the cookie values and adding a `hash` key to the cookies. I call the logic to secure the cookies from `EndRequest`, so that in my app code, I can do whatever I need with cookies and secure everything once I know I'm done with all changes to the contents of the cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EndRequest` is the last event in the pipeline to be executed. It is called after the response is sent. You cannot use it to manipulate the response. It's most common uses are logging and transaction manipulation.

You should consider implementing a `HttpMessageHandler`.

```
public class MyHttpMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{         
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // do something with request ...
        // ...

        // process request
        var response =  await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // do something with response
        // ...

        return response;
    }
}
```

Then you need to register it

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                   .MessageHandlers
                   .Add(new HttpMessageHandler());
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it worked perfectly. But why does WebApi call EndRequest after it's already sent the Response?

Comment: `EndRequest` is the last event in the pipeline to be executed. It is called after the response is sent. You cannot use it to manipulate the response. It's most common uses are logging and transaction manipulation.

Comment: But then why does it work to modify the cookies in EndRequest when using WebForms or MVC? I only have this issue in WebApi.